# Having an array of values how to form a frames grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frame

So I have an array with 3 items - `'a', 'b', 'c'` I want ot create inside some `div` a `frameset` grid (resizable if possible) where each frame has its source in `someStringVar + arrayItem[i].ToString()` How to do such thing with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<frameset id="myframeset">
</frameset>
```

jS

```
var myArray  = ['a','b','c'];
var cols = [];

for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) cols.push((100/myArray.length)+"%");

$("#myframeset").attr("cols", cols.toString());

for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    $("frame", { src: "http://www.mysite.com/"+myArray[i]+.".htm" }).appendTo("#myframeset");
}
```